# PowerShell on Linux - How to load \ use .Net assemblies?

Tags: .net, linux, powershell, ubuntu, mono

Now that PowerShell is [open sourced](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and available on [Linux](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-is-open-sourced-and-is-available-on-linux/), any one knows how to add .Net assemblies under linux? if at all possible?

I have installed PS on Ubuntu 16.04 as in [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docs/installation/linux.md#ubuntu-1604) and installed Mono as in [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).

After running PS on terminal, this line surprisingly works just fine:

```
add-type -assembly "/usr/lib/mono/4.5-api/System.Web.Extensions.dll"
```

No errors etc...

Yet when I try to:

```
$js = New-Object "System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer"
```

I am getting this error:

```
new-object : Cannot find type [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]: verify that the 
assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:10
+ $ps_js = new-object "System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerial ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Any hints on that one?
Is it a bug maybe as powershell on linux is still "alpha"?

BTW - On windows all is working just fine...

Comment: Miguel de Icaza confirmed it does not work with Mono yet, so you can only run it with .NET Core right now.

Comment: Any reference to that confirmation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell on Linux is based on CoreCLR while mono is a clone of the CLR / full framework. The assembly you are using is a full framework one and cannot load in CoreCLR since it is based on mscorlib and not System.Runtime.

In a year there will be a workaround (maybe) with the upcoming .NET Standard 2.0.

Json serialization should be native in PowerShell, if not use newtonsoft.json.